# Deserializing JSON Data which contain arrays

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

I would like to deserialize JSON data which has three keys as follows : Type, Name, Data[]

My Message class which I want my JSON to be serialized into :

```
class Message
{
    public int Type;
    public string Name;
    public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> Data;
}
```

I am able to deserialize Type and Name with this block of code;

```
Message DeserializedMessage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Message>(myString);
Console.WriteLine("Name: " + DeserializedMessage.Name);
Console.WriteLine("Type: " + DeserializedMessage.Type);
```

However, I don't have any clue to how to deserialize the key-value pairs in JSON to my `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> Data;`

Example JSONs :

```
{
    "Type":"103",
    "Name":"Oguzhan",
    "Data":
    [
        {
            "InviteTo":"Bahadir"
        }
    ]
}

{
    "Type":"104",
    "Name":"Oguzhan",
    "Data":
    [
        {
            "Game":"Backgammon",
            "Duration":"2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your

```
public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> data;
```

to

```
public List<Dictionary<string, string>> data;
```

After that, it's relatively easy:

```
Message message = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Message>(jsonString);
```

Or, if you would like to use `dynamic`:

```
dynamic parsed = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);
Message message = MapToMessage(parsed);

// ...

private Message MapToMessage(dynamic json)
{
    return new Message()
    {
        Type = json.Type,
        Name = json.Name,
        Data = ((IEnumerable<dynamic>)json.Data).Select(d =>
        {
            var dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            foreach (var v in d) dic.Add(v.Name, v.Value.Value);
            return dic;
         }).ToList()
    };
}
```